# How can I get the sum of several columns grouping by other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

What I'm trying to do is replicate this SQL code to Python:

```
select column_1, column_2, column_3, 
       sum(column_4) as sum_column_4, sum(column_5) as sum_column_5
from df 
group by 1,2,3;
```

In other words, I need to make this data frame:

```
column_1   column_2   colunn_3   column_4   column_5
AA         BB         CC         5          3
AA         BB         CC         5          0
AA         BB         CC         7          3
AA         DD         EE         5          2
AA         DD         EE         7          1
DD         EE         FF         2          8
DD         EE         FF         1          0
```

Look like this:

```
column_1   column_2   colunn_3   sum_column_4   sum_column_5
AA         BB         CC         17             6
AA         DD         EE         12             3
DD         EE         FF         3              8
```

Also, I'm trying to make this as simple as possible, because I actually have a lot of columns. And I need to have a new Pandas data frame as output. 
So this is what I've tried:

```
df.groupby(list(df.columns)[0:3]).sum()
```

It's almost there, the problem is that the output gets weird, something like:

```
column_1   column_2   colunn_3   sum_column_4   sum_column_5
AA         BB         CC         17             6
           DD         EE         12             3
DD         EE         FF         3              8
```

I'm trying different things that I've seen in other posts, like [Pandas DataFrame Groupby two columns and get counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679089/pandas-dataframe-groupby-two-columns-and-get-counts) and [Python Pandas group by multiple columns, mean of another - no group by object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268619/python-pandas-group-by-multiple-columns-mean-of-another-no-group-by-object), but that didn't work. So if anyone could help me.

Comment: `df.groupby(['column_1','column_2','column_3']).sum()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang the problem with this is that the output is a little weird. For instance, if I have AA + BB + CC in one line and AA + DD + EE in another, the column 1 will not be filled with "AA" in the second row, just for the first. That's why I used SQL as example of what I'm replicating

Comment: @QuangHoang I've updated the question with the problem

Comment: You see the missing label because they are index. chain that with `reset_index()`

Comment: @QuangHoang it worked! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Quang mentioned in comments, you need to reset indexing:

```
df.groupby(list(df.columns)[0:3]).sum().reset_index()
```

When you groupby multiple columns at once, you create a hierarchical multi-indexing and that is why you see `column_1` groups index `AA`.

output:

```
  column_1 column_2 colunn_3  column_4  column_5
0       AA       BB       CC        17         6
1       AA       DD       EE        12         3
2       DD       EE       FF         3         8
```